# Cannot view product page on Magento after theme installation

Tags: magento, product

I recently added a new theme onto an existing magento site, everything went fine with the transition. However, when trying to view a product page I get a long list of errors:

```
There has been an error processing your request

Invalid method Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple::displayProductStockStatus(Array())
```

Trace:

```
#0 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml(5): Varien_Object->__call('displayProductS...', Array)
#1 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml(5): Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Type_Simple->displayProductStockStatus()
#2 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#3 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
#4 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#5 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#6 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#7 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('product_type_da...', true)
#8 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view.phtml(83): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('product_type_da...')
#9 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#10 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
#11 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#14 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#15 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(582): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(526): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#17 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/design/frontend/smartwave/porto/template/page/1column.phtml(48): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#18 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/var/www/vhosts...')
#19 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('frontend/smartw...')
#20 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#21 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(863): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#22 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#23 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#24 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(137): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#25 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/Helper/Page.php(52): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->_renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route-2')
#26 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Cms/controllers/IndexController.php(75): Mage_Cms_Helper_Page->renderPage(Object(Mage_Cms_IndexController), 'no-route-2')
#27 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(419): Mage_Cms_IndexController->noRouteAction()
#28 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('noRoute')
#29 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(176): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#30 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#31 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/app/Mage.php(683): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#32 /var/www/vhosts/coastallinensupplies.co.uk/dev/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#33 {main}
```

Does anyone know why is this happening and how it could be resolved?

EDIT: The code causing the issue is:

```
<?php /* $_product = $this->getProduct() ?>

<?php echo $this->getPriceHtml($_product) ?>

<?php if ($this->displayProductStockStatus()): ?>
    <?php if ($_product->isAvailable()): ?>
        <p class="availability in-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('In stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php else: ?>
        <p class="availability out-of-stock"><?php echo $this->__('Availability:') ?> <span><?php echo $this->__('Out of stock') ?></span></p>
    <?php endif; ?>
<?php endif; ?>

<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('product_type_data_extra')
*/
 ?>
```

If I comment this out everything works fine, would just be good to know why it is breaking the page.

Comment: Did the theme you installed have models, controllers, blocks etc in the code pool? If so, it doesn't look like they're being loaded. You might want to check that you've installed all the necessary configuration XML files, i.e. the one in app/etc that represents the module, and the one in app/code/local(or community)/Vendor/Module/etc/config.xml

Comment: I guess the problem is in the file `smartwave/porto/template/catalog/product/view/type/default.phtml` could you share the code please.